# Is synchronized block always needed with synchronized collections?

Tags: java, synchronized

Considering there is:

- `Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<>());`
- Main looping `Thread`

  - Performs scheduled tasks (from blocking queue) on map above.

    - Tasks can be basically anything you can do with map (also iterating and updating values inside).
- Multiple looping "mini" Threads

  - That need lookup every now and then on **current** elements of map (only iterating, no edition).

Now - **current** is keyword here - I need to have straight flow - can't use snapshots.

As per docs: (but I am unsure what can I do)

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views.

What I need exactly is whenever map is modified or being **iterated over** by **main thread**, none of "mini" threads can access it (lock).

At the same time, when main thread is not touching said map - all "mini" threads can access map however they like (but they will not modify it in any way - just iterate/read).

But now - what happens when main thread would want to modify map while "mini"s are iterating over it?

Does this mean I need to put map in synchronized block whenever possible?

Would ReadWriteLock help here? Keep in mind that lookup for "mini" threads can't be a snapshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collections.synchronizedMap()` will synchronize access to each method of the map, however the methods on an `Iterator` are all called separately, which is why *you* have to synchronize on the map for the duration of the iteration.

Synchronization is an *exclusive* lock, so only one thread can iterating the map as a time. If you have many reader (iterators) and want them to execute in parallel, you should definitely replace synchronization with the use of [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). The concurrent implementations are not a viable alternative for you, since you said "can't use snapshots".

That means, don't wrap the `LinkedHashMap` using `Collections.synchronizedMap()`. Instead, create a [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html), and *always* obtain locks around *any* use of the map, using `readLock()` for readers (iteration, `get()`, `containsKey()`, etc), and `writeLock()` for mutators (`put()`, `remove()`, iteration with `remove()`, etc).

Comment: About ReentrantReadWriteLock - I used it in past, but was never sure about that "snapshot" part I mentioned in question. Doesn't read/write lock actually create such snapshot? I mean - what happens if multiple "mini" readers are iterating over and writer (main thread) add something to map? Won't that be missed in run?

Comment: ReentrantReadWriteLock does not create snapshots. It is just mechanism to select which thread is allowed to run. Multiple threads can have read lock  simultaneously, but only on thread can have write lock. Basically the writer can not get lock when readers are having it and vice versa.

Comment: @Ernio Writer thread *cannot* write while readers are iterating. That's the entire point of using locks. Since a reader thread maintains the read lock for the duration of the iteration, the writer thread will have to wait until iteration completes, before being allowed write access to the map. No snapshot involved.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I need. :P

Comment: @Ernio You should probably make the lock "[fair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#ReentrantReadWriteLock-boolean-)", to prevent multiple iterating threads from "hogging" the map.

Comment: @SeanBright It is the only answer that will allow multiple *parallel* iterations without the use of *snapshots*. Unless you have another answer for that particular combo, which is exactly the combo that was asked for in the question: 1) Single main thread updating map. 2) Multiple read-only "mini" threads iterating map. 3) Can't use snapshots. --- Still, I up-voted your comment for the useful reminder of `try-finally`.

Comment: @SeanBright Reading between the lines: *"At the same time, when main thread is not touching said map - **all "mini" threads can access map however they like** [...] Would `ReadWriteLock` help here?"* Short answer: Yes. Long answer: See above.

Answer (score 3):

If you need exclusive write access to the `Map`, then you should synchronize. You don't need to use `Collections.synchronizedMap()`, just make sure that you are always synchronizing on the same object:

```
private final Map<Whatever> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

/* Your writer thread */
public void run()
{
    synchronized (myMap) {
       /* Write, iterate, whatever */
    }
}

/* Your reader thread */
public void run()
{
    synchronized (myMap) {
       /* Read stuff */
    }
}
```

Only one thread can enter a `synchronized` block for a given object at the same time. So your writer thread and reader threads will never be working on your map at the same time.

Make sure to do as little work as possible within the `synchronized` blocks and leave them as soon as you are done to reduce contention.

Bear in mind that synchronizing (serializing) access to a `Map` (or any object) is **completely different** than using the synchronized wrappers returned by the methods on `Collections`. Just because you are using the `Map` returned by `Collections.synchronizedMap()` does not mean that your code is thread safe. That applies equally to `ConcurrentHashMap` as well. Just because it has `Concurrent` in the name, doesn't mean you can't use it in a thread-unsafe manner.

Comment: That moment when you are so busy looking into concurrent packages you forget about basic solutions.

Comment: Feel free to use a `Lock` but synchronization is probably sufficient. If you find that there is a lot of contention, you can switch to another concurrency control mechanism.

Comment: `Collections.synchronizedMap()` is just a way to "automatically" wrap all methods on the map with a `synchronized` block. Not using `Collections.synchronizedMap()` just means you have to do it yourself, which means: 1) More code. 2) Error-prone (you may forget to do it). --- As such, I think this answer isn't a good answer to the question.

Comment: The same shortcomings can be applied to using a RWL. Manual synchronizing over `Map` operations is not the same thing as using a `Map` whose methods are synchronized.

Comment: True, with `ReadWriteLock` you don't have much choice, but your answer is not about RWL at all, but is advocating manual `synchronized` blocks over the use of `synchronizedMap()`, and *that* is why I believe the answer isn't good.

Comment: I have no question. None of my comments did. And I stand by what I said: `synchronizedMap()` is just a way to "automatically" wrap all methods with a `synchronized` block. `containsKey()` and `get()` are *two* method calls, not one. --- Besides, your second example can *still* fail with `NullPointerException`, unless you disallow `null` values (not stated anywhere), and if you do disallow nulls, a null check after `get()` would be better, since it would also work for synchronized and concurrent collections, and it would eliminate double map lookup *(micro-optimization, and yes, I know!)*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to synchronize somehow to avoid concurrent modifications while iterating.

If write operations are a lot less frequent than read operations, then a `ReadWriteLock` might be the right tool for you.

Otherwise, `synchronized`-blocks are probably the easiest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean I need to put map in synchronized block whenever possible?

Not wherever possible but only when you are obtaining **iterator** on that collection. 
Because except iterator() all other methods are synchronized for you when you ask for a synchronized collection using synchronizedMap() API.

For e.g. if you want to obtain size of the collection, no need to have yourmap.size() call within a synchronized block as the decorator handles synchronization for you.

You can refer [Collections.java](http://www.docjar.net/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html) for further reference.